Powershell create Access>External Data; Link Specification' does not exist. You cannot import, export, or link using the specification
I have access to a remote database that consists of over 100+ csv files with a dozen columns and over 150k lines in each file; about 16g of total data.  I need to create an Access external link to each file for pulling pivot data to be exported for each individual file.  I can do this manually with Access>External Data>New Data Source>From File>Text File> file address” and then create a query for each linked file. When I use a PS script it fails.
My intent is to create these Access links with Powershell.
The following is an example of by script;
$filePath = "$env:userprofile\Desktop\Donation_Data\itcont_2020_20191129_20191224.csv"

$accessApp = New-Object -ComObject Access.Application

$accessApp.Visible = "True"   #I want to see Access opened to make sure the link is installed

$databasePath = "$env:userprofile\Desktop\Donations.accdb"

$accessApp.OpenCurrentDatabase($databasePath)

$db = $accessApp.CurrentDb()

$tableDef = $db.CreateTableDef("itcont_2020_20191129_20191224")

$tableDef.SourceTableName = "itcont_2020_20191129_20191224.csv"

$tableDef.Connect = "Text;DSN=itcont_2020_20191129_20191224 Link Specification;FMT=Delimited;HDR=NO;IMEX=2;CharacterSet=437;ACCDB=YES;DATABASE=C:\Users\fkram\Desktop\Donation_Data"

$db.TableDefs.Append($tableDef)

$tableDef   #Shows the tableDef configuration is in memory ready to be appended.


The problem shows after implementing $db.TableDefs.Append($tableDef).  You received the error OperationStopped: The text file specification ' itcont_2020_20191129_20191224 Link Specification' does not exist. You cannot import, export, or link using the specification.
Here is the thing.  I can manually link the same csv file using Access and following Access>External Data>New Data Source>From File>Text File>” file address.  When I then pull the $db.TableDefs command in powershell it shows the exact same configuration as $tableDef configuration I tried to append.
Now the interesting aspect.  If I delete the manually installed link, then re implement the powershell $db.TableDefs.Append($tableDef) command it works.  It seems there is something about using the above powershell script that has a missing step that interferes with the link being installed correctly.
Any ideas?

Sorry to make this such a fast fix, however I solved the problem without understanding if it is a  bug or not.  Playing around with;
$tableDef.Connect = "Text;DSN=itcont_2020_20191129_20191224 Link Specification;FMT=Delimited;HDR=NO;IMEX=2;CharacterSet=437;ACCDB=YES;DATABASE=C:\Users\fkram\Desktop\Donation_Data"
I modified one portion of the line from "Text;DSN=itcont" to "Text;DSN = itcont"; adding a space before and after the "=" sign.  Do not ask  me why this works, you just need to add a space here to get the command to implement.
Strange.

Please properly format your post, besides I recomment you to add an actual and an expected output example. See also how to ask
